# PHP/Regex - Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier

Tags: php, regex

Guys i've got this error:

`Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier 'E' in /home/sportsdi/public_html/test/index.php on line 17`

Here is my code:

```
<?PHP
$url = "http://www.sportsdirect.com/donnay-10-pack-trainer-socks-411038?colcode=41103890";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
 $str = curl_exec($curl);  
 curl_close($curl);  


$SIZEID = 'UK: 8-13 Kids / EU: 25-32 Kids';
$occurencies = preg_match_all('/(?<=\"SizeName\":\"'.$SIZEID.'")\S+/i', $str, $match);


echo $occurencies;
```

It seems the problem comes from `/` symbol in the `$SIZEID` variable.
It is important to search with this symbol. Any advice how i can fix this problem ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple use [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) like this:

(This escape every regular expression character)

```
$occurencies = preg_match_all('/(?<=\"SizeName\":\"' . preg_quote($SIZEID, "/") . '")\S+/i', $str, $match);
                                                     //^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_quote` to take care of escaping characters in your variable:

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=\"SizeName\":\"' . preg_quote($SIZEID, '/') . '")\S+/i', $str, $match);
```

The second parameter is a forward slash by default - it should match up with whatever you're using to begin and end your regular expression.

Comment: Using your advice i got this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/sportsdi/public_html/test/index.php on line 17`